# C++ Why pointer value changed?

Tags: c++, pointers, struct, linked-list

I just testing a linked link. However, the list address passed to function GetElement() is not expected after I insert a element to the list and the list should be a reference type. I just can't understand why.

This is my main program:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

typedef struct Node
{
    int data;
    struct Node *next;
} Node;

typedef struct Node *LinkList;

void InsertElement(LinkList *header, int i, int e)
{
    LinkList p = *header;
    int j = 0;

    while (p && j < i)
    {
        p = p->next;
        j++;
    }

    if (!p || j > i)
        return;

    Node newNode;
    newNode.data = e;
    newNode.next = p->next;

    p->next = &newNode;
}

void GetElement(LinkList list, int i, int *value)
{
    LinkList p = list->next;
    int j = 1;
    while (p && j < i)
    {
        p = p->next;
        j++;
    }
    if (!p || j >= i)
        return;

    *value = p->data;
}
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    LinkList header = (LinkList)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    header->next = NULL;

    InsertElement(&header, 0, 1);
    int res = -1;
    GetElement(header, 1, &res);

}
```

When I am debugging, I found the parameter "list" in function GetElement() changed once it enters the function.

Comment: You should use a class with a constructor, `malloc()` should be avoided in C++, also you could use references instead of pointers

Comment: When you pass by value you make a copy.  You've copied the entire LinkList when passing to your function.  You should pass by reference instead.

Comment: Using typedef to hide pointers makes the code harder to read and maintain.  Also, why `malloc` instead of `new`?  And further, why dynamically allocate in `main` to begin with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a problem:

```
Node newNode;
...
p->next = &newNode; // <<== Using a pointer to local
```

`newNode` above is a local variable that goes out of scope, along with its memory, as soon as the function exits. This causes undefined behavior, because the memory for the node is deallocated.

Using `malloc` instead, the way that you did in the `_tmain`, will fix the problem. Better yet, use `new`, since this is C++, and `malloc` is a C-style allocation.

Once you fix this issue, another issue related to the number of nodes will pop up: you are allocating a node which is assigned to the `head`, but it is left unused. Since you are passing a pointer to a pointer anyway, you should pass a pointer to `header`, and modify it through a double-pointer.

Comment: Thanks! These codes came from a old C program. I should use new instead malloc.

Answer (score 0):

Your program is exhibiting the symptoms of undefined behavior. The undefined behavior is caused by the following lines in `InsertElement`.

```
Node newNode;
newNode.data = e;
newNode.next = p->next;

p->next = &newNode;
```

You are returning a pointer to an object on the stack. The pointer is not valid once you return from the function. Later on, in `GetElement`, you are accessing that pointer.

What you need to use instead:

```
Node* newNode = new Node;
newNode->data = e;
newNode->next = p->next;

p->next = newNode;
```

Comment: Thanks! That makes a lot more sense.